# how to send props to an already visible component in react

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I can only find ReactJS reading and examples on how to send props when Component is created.
The constructor runs and receive the props ok.
But what if the Component is already created and need to have new props to updated something!
I really efter hours cant find information on this please advice?

Answer (score 1):

If you send some props to the component, the component is updated straight off the props or state has been updated.

```
const App = () => {
  const [caption, setCaption] = useState("My component")

  return <Component caption={caption} />
}
const Component = ({caption}) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
  return (
    <h2>{caption} was updated {counter} times</h2>
  )
}
```

In this example,  updates when either prop 'caption' or state 'counter' has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Give the child Component the prop (can just be `null` by default at the start) and then when a State-change occurs in the parent element it will re-render the child with the new prop.

[React Docs on Updating](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating)